# sequence increment like 2018AA000001, 2018AB000001, 2018AC000001

Tags: postgresql

I need to increment sequence like 2018AA000001 to 2018AA100000 after completing first sequence then it should start next sequence 2018AB000001 to 2018AB100000

it is working only one sequence using trigger in postgresql but i need to implement 2018AA then 2018AB, 2018AC sequence like.

please suggest me how to do this.

Thanks,
Vittal

Answer (score 0):

You can probably make a function out of this. Maybe some people here can edit this into a sequence that you can use.
This output the results you specified in your description.

```
discard temp;
```

We will generate list of letters using this.

```
create temp table generate_letters as
select chr(i) as letter from generate_series(65,90) i;
```

```
 letter 
--------
 A
 B
 C
 D
 E
 F
 G
 H
 I
 J
 K
 L
 M
 N
 O
 P
 Q
 R
 S
 T
 U
 V
 W
 X
 Y
 Z
(26 rows)
```

And generate numbers up to 100000.

```
create temp table generate_num as
select lpad(i::text,6,'0') as num from generate_series(1,100000) i;
```

```
select * from generate_num limit 10;
  num   
--------
 000001
 000002
 000003
 000004
 000005
 000006
 000007
 000008
 000009
 000010
(10 rows)
```

Then we just have to cross join.

```
select concat_ws('','2018',gl1.letter,gl2.letter,d.num) as seq
from       generate_letters gl1
cross join generate_letters gl2
cross join generate_num d limit 100003;
```

```
     seq      
--------------
 2018AA000001
 2018AA000002
 2018AA000003
 2018AA000004
 2018AA000005
 2018AA000006
 2018AA000007
 2018AA000008
 2018AA000009
...skipping...
 2018AA099997
 2018AA099998
 2018AA099999
 2018AA100000
 2018AB000001
 2018AB000002
```

Comment: i have a table with column id and i need to increment using above query. please suggest me.